# Ubuntu audio issues

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

This work for me:

First check if your device is being recognized with `sudo alsamixer`

In my case the default device was empty but using <kbd>F6</kbd> my sound card was recognized, but it wasn't working.

I tried reinstalling, reloading, removing alsa and pulse audio but nothing worked.

So, instead of uninstalling PulseAudio  I disabled autospawning by editing `/etc/pulse/client.conf` and replacing:

```
; autospawn = yes
```

with

```
autospawn = no
```

Then `pulseaudio -k`

After that I had to force the default device.

Setting the default device:

Find your desired card with:

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

and then create `/etc/asound.conf` with following:

```
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.ctl.card 1
```

Replace "1" with number of your card determined above.

The sound icon is still missing on the icon tray but the sound is working fine now.

What is missing to solve the icon issue.

Comment: What version and flavor/desktop of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 19.04 disco
DE: GNOME